# How to fetch the substring from the input string in command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following string

```
set var="/host=the_host/core-service=vault:add(vault-options=[("KEYSTORE_URL" => "C:\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\bin\vault\vault.keystore"),("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" => "MASK-18BzezESSkb72WrhEf6Rsu"),("KEYSTORE_ALIAS" => "vault"),("SALT" => "1234abcd"),("ITERATION_COUNT" => "120"),("ENC_FILE_DIR" => "C:\wildfly-15.0.1.Final\bin\vault/")])"
```

I want to extract only the `MASK-18BzezESSkb72WrhEf6Rsu` value alone using windows batch. I have tried using the **`for`** but couldn't find anything to fetch the password alone.

Comment: Where is the string? Are we supposed to guess? `findstr.exe` matches lines containing patterns, not substrings within lines matching patterns. You are not new to this site, so should be well aware that this is not a code writing service. We help you to fix issues with your provided code, so you need to write and try some, before you can ask us to fix a reproducible issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "string=/core-service=vault:add(vault-options=[("KEYSTORE_URL" => "C:\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\bin\vault\vault.keystore"),("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" => "MASK-18BzezESSkb72WrhEf6Rsu"),("KEYSTORE_ALIAS" => "vault"),("SALT" => "1234abcd"),("ITERATION_COUNT" => "120"),("ENC_FILE_DIR" => "C:\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\bin\vault/")])"

SET "string=%string:"=%"
SET "string=%string:>=%"
SET "string=%string:<=%"
SET "string=%string:)=%"
SET "string=%string:(=%"

SET "password="

FOR %%e IN (%string%) DO IF DEFINED password (
  SET "password=%%e"
  GOTO found
 ) ELSE  IF /i "%%e"=="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" SET "password=next"

ECHO password NOT found
GOTO :eof

:found
ECHO password is "%password%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Remove the awkward characters by uing string-substitution then run through the remaining list of words, if the string in the word before is found, set `password` as a flag, and grab the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also how can we achieve the same in bash?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid - never had a bash at **bash**.